# Can't get elements with specific id as attribute 'data-parent'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a element like this

```
<input type="checkbox" data-parent="0" value="1229">
```

and I want to get all the checkboxes with data-parent that have a value of N.

Here is what I tried in my click event handler method.

```
checkChildren = function (id) {
    var cbs = $(input[type="checkbox"][data-parent=id]);
}
```

but there is some syntax error near 'data-parent=id'

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS selector is wrong. Change it to:

```
var cbs = $('input[type="checkbox"][data-parent="' + id + '"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass a string selector to jquery, first building it with a javascript expression
additionally, the html tag attribute values (`"checkbox"` and `"0"`) need to both be quoted

```
var selector = 'input[type="checkbox"][data-parent="' + id + '"]';
var cbs = $(selector);
```

---

*edit, details why:*
`input[type="checkbox"][data-parent=id]`
when the javascript parser hits this, it tries to execute it as javascript code, and give the result to `$()`.

Here's what it (javascript parsing engine) tries:

- looks for a variable named `input`
- Finds an opening bracket `[` after the `input` object and evaluates the contents, `type="checkbox"`
  *(this operation sets the variable `type` to the string `"checkbox"` and returns the string `"checkbox"`)*
- substitutes the returned value into the first brackets, `input["checkbox"`]
  *(the bracket operator looks up the `checkbox` property of the `input` object, like `input.checkbox`, and returns the `value` of the property or `undefined`)*
- Similarly evaluates for the second set of brackets `value[data-parent=id]`
  *(but this time runs into an error because `data-parent=id` is ambiguous, it's trying to set the result of `subtract parent from data` to the variable `id`)*